# Image is not showing in page using react

Tags: reactjs

The image is not showing in webpage.
Image code I am using

```
<img src={{uri: ConfigFile.ImageBaseUrl + carImage}} alt="new xuv's" />
```

And the output showing in the browser is

```
 <img src=[object object] alt="new xuv's" />
```

Comment: Yes, you are passing an object, you have to pass a String. Try using Template strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct you are passing object as URL? So react sees it as object, try to do something like:

```
<img src={ConfigFile.ImageBaseUrl + carImage} />
```

Should see it as a string and should load it correctly :)

Comment: Very nice glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass an object to src, You can pass the image URL.

```
<img src={ConfigFile.ImageBaseUrl + carImage} alt="new xuv's" />
```